# Can pytest fixtures and confest.py modules be shared across packages?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Suppose I have `packageA` which provides a class `usefulClass`, pytest fixtures in a `test_stuff.py` module, and test configurations in a `conftest.py` module.

Moreover, suppose that I have `packageB`and `packageC` both of which import `packageA`, installed via `pip`, and that they use `usefulClass` in the same way. Because they use `usefulClass` in the same way, `packageB` and `packageC` will require many identical pytest fixtures and configurations. In fact, their tests will primarily differ only in the sets of inputs over which they iterate.

Because the fixtures and configurations are identical and arise from the use of `usefulClass`, is it possible to define those fixtures and configurations in `packageA`, and then import them into the testing environments of `packageB` and `packageC`?

In particular, I would like to reuse the definition of `pytest_generate_tests` that appears in `packageA`'s `conftest.py` module across dozens, if not hundreds of other packages. This way, I only need maintain one `confest.py` module, rather than hundreds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `conftest.py` file is not part of the module and cannot be imported from other modules.

However you could create a module `packageA.testutils`, which you then can import in all `conftest.py` files, including `packageA`'s:

```
from packageA.testutils import *
```

Maybe it even warrants creating an individual package that all your other packages depend on.

Comment: I was thinking something like this might be the only option. So if I import the specially named configuration functions, such as `pytest_generate_tests`, from `packageA.testutils` into `packageB`'s `conftest.py`, pytest will correctly discover and apply them?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it in one of my packages. `pytest_generate_tests` imported into a dependent package's `conftest.py` does get correctly discovered and executed; so, I will assume the same is true of any other specially named functions. Vielen Dank ~MM

Comment: You could use: `pytest_plugins = [ "packageA.testutils"]` in the `conftest.py` at the root of your project. Check [pytest plugins documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/plugins.html).