# How to distribute conftest.py and fixtures from a project across different repo/projects?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, python-wheel, conftest

I could not find a solid example on doing so. Here is the situation.
I have several fixtures written in a Python file called `my_fixtures.py` & a `conftest.py` containing configuration for the fixtures like below:

```
import pytest

from glob import glob    

def refactor(string: str) -> str:
    return string.replace("/", ".").replace("\\", ".").replace(".py", "")    

pytest_plugins = [
    refactor(fixture) for fixture in glob("tests/fixtures/*.py") if "__" not in fixture
]    

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    # execute all other hooks to obtain the report object
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
```

meanwhile in `my_fixtures.py`, here are the codes:

```
@pytest.fixture
def transport(resource) -> Transport:
    ...
    return t    

@pytest.fixture
def microservice(transport, request, resource) -> Microservice:
    ...
    yield m
    m.stop_logging()  # must stop logging handler
```

Both files above are located in Project A with the folder structure below:

```
project-a
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┗ joebus
 ┃ ┃ ┣ topics.py
 ┃ ┃ ┗ __init__.py
 ┗ tests
 ┃ ┣ fixtures
 ┃ ┃ ┗ my_fixtures.py
 ┃ ┣ conftest.py
 ┃ ┗ test_simple.py
```

Let say I have another project called `project-b`, and it needs to use the fixtures from project-a's `my_fixtures.py` & the test cases in `project-b` needs to use everything in project-a's `conftest.py`, how this can be done via `pip install project-a`?

P/S: I have studied the [only article](https://gist.github.com/peterhurford/09f7dcda0ab04b95c026c60fa49c2a68) discussing it and other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765901/can-pytest-fixtures-and-confest-py-modules-be-shared-across-packages), but I would like to see an example.

Thanks